# Выборка из таблицы, где первые элементы с type = 1

Tags: select, sql

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать выборку из таблицы SQL, где первые элементы будут type = 1, а дальше остальные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если mysql, то можно так:

```
select * from tab
order by find_in_set(type,1) desc, id
```

Answer (score 1):

[Стандартное решение](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html)

```
select * from tab
order by case type when 1 then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: Простите, у вас, видимо, кирка для data mining'a другая. Откуда вы взяли, что другие значения будут именно 2?

Comment: Они не будут 2, они будут сортироваться после 1.
Если вам не нрвится 2, можете взять любое число большее 1.